# How to add a python module to PYTHONPATH in a virtual environment?

Tags: python, bash, python-module

I am running a virtual environment (venv) to run python 3.7. I have a module my_module that I downloaded from a repo. I wish to add it to my PYTHONPATH so I can just write "import my_module" in my python scripts wherever. I read that I need to do something to my .bashrc file, but I can't find it on my Mac. There's no file named "./.bashrc", "./.bash_profile" or "./.profile" on my Mac. Do I need to create it or something?

Answer (score 0):

If you downloaded a module, you should have gotten what is called a Python wheel. This isn't the exact code, but rather a package that includes the necessary code to install. What you want to do, listed [here](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#installing-from-local-archives), is to run `pip install` on it to include it as part of your virtual environment. This way, the module should be visible globally so long as you are running it from your venv.

**If downloaded straight from source**

The repo should contain a set amount of source files, as you've stated, one of which is a `setup.py` file. <s>You should need to run `python setup.py install` inside your virtual environment, and it'll install itself that way.</s> Running `pip install .` should be able to install the package instead, and it should be safer than directly calling setup.py. (thanks to chepner in comments for the clarification)

Comment: I cloned a repo continuing this module using git. There was no zip file or wheel file. It is just a folder with __init__.py and other folders containing python scripts.

Comment: ahhh I see okay so in that case you want to look at setup.py. I'll update the answer with steps

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into that. I appreciate any help you can give.

Comment: Definitely yeah! If this doesn't work, I'd recommend [this](https://www.activestate.com/resources/quick-reads/how-to-manually-install-python-packages/) since it should have some more instructions on how to set it up

Comment: `pip install .` should run `setup.py install` for you; try to avoid using `setup.py` directly.

Comment: I had no idea, updated the answer with that; thanks @chepner

Comment: So there's no setup.py. Like I said, its just a folder with a __init__.py script and some other scripts. Am I suppose to make a setup.py following those instructions?